# Changes in Perron eigenvector given a particular perturbation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a matrix with real and strictly positive elements ($a_{ij}>0$). The row or columns of A do not add to one or to the same number. Let $x^A$ be the Perron vector of the matrix, normalized so that $\sum_i x_i^A = 1$.

Let $B$ be a new matrix with real and positive elements formed by perturbing $A$ in the following way: $b_{1j} > a_{1j}$ and $b_{ij} < a_{ij}$ for all $i \geq 2$. Let $x^B$ be the Perron vector under the same normalization.

Is it possible to show that $x_1^B > x_1^A$ and $x_i^B < x_i^A$ for all $i \geq 2$? Under what restrictions or conditions (properties of $A$ and $B$) would this be satisfied?